# spring boot 1.3.6 BeanCreationException SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I build a spring boot micro-app .
All codes are fine in spring boot 1.3.5 and Brixton.SR1

But after upgrade spring boot to 1.3.6,met a start error .

Don't know How to resolve it ..

```
2016-07-08 09:10:05.121 Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration.mbeanExporter; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter] is defined: more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates: [mbeanExporter, integrationMbeanExporter, endpointMBeanExporter]
2016-07-08 09:10:05.133 Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
 Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
 Stopping service Tomcat
 Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration.mbeanExporter; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter] is defined: more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates: [mbeanExporter, integrationMbeanExporter, endpointMBeanExporter]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at com.xdidian.keryhu.user_account.Application.main(Application.java:15) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration.mbeanExporter; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter] is defined: more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates: [mbeanExporter, integrationMbeanExporter, endpointMBeanExporter]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter] is defined: more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates: [mbeanExporter, integrationMbeanExporter, endpointMBeanExporter]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.determinePrimaryCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1255) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.determineAutowireCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1216) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1124) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted

[2016-07-08 09:10:05.186Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/Users/hushuming/Desktop/git-repo/xdidian-projection/user-account/target/classes/]
```

What's thee reason ?

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/6328 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As martin said, this is unfortunately a regression in Spring Boot `1.3.6.RELEASE` but there is a workaround:

Add this configuration in your own `@Configuration` class for the time being:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationMBeanExporter integrationMbeanExporter(
           @Value("spring.jmx.default-domain") String domain, 
           MBeanServer mBeanServer) {
       IntegrationMBeanExporter exporter = new IntegrationMBeanExporter();
       exporter.setDefaultDomain(domain);
       exporter.setServer(mBeanServer);
       return exporter;
}

@Bean
@Primary
public AnnotationMBeanExporter mbeanExporter(ObjectNamingStrategy namingStrategy, MBeanServer mBeanServer) {
    AnnotationMBeanExporter exporter = new AnnotationMBeanExporter();
    exporter.setRegistrationPolicy(RegistrationPolicy.FAIL_ON_EXISTING);
    exporter.setNamingStrategy(namingStrategy);
    exporter.setServer(mBeanServer);
    return exporter;
}
```